# Prisma findMany query not working for one to many relationship

Tags: next.js, prisma, next.js13

I'm using Prisma w/ Postgres and am trying to have a simple 1-to-many relationship with a Collection and Product which we have zero or more Product(s). I am not able to fetch record using below query. Please help.

```
const collections = await db.collection.findMany({
    where: {
      userId: user.id,
      products: {
        every: {
          productStatus: ProductStatus.ACTIVATED,
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

Below is the schema I am using

```
model Product {
  productId     String        @id @default(cuid())
  poster        Poster?
  productType   ProductType   @default(METALPOSTER)
  title         String
  userId        String         
  description   String
  productStatus ProductStatus
  url           String?
  orderItems    OrderItem[]
  createdAt     DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime      @updatedAt
  user          User         @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  isFeatured    Boolean       @default(false)
  isDeleted     Boolean       @default(false)
  cartItems     cartItems[]
  collectionId String
  collection   Collection     @relation(fields: [collectionId], references: [collectionId])
  Price          Price?       @relation(fields: [priceProductId], references: [productId])
  priceProductId String?
}

model Collection {
  collectionId String   @id @default(cuid())
  userId       String?
  title        String
  description  String?  @default("")
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt
  user         User?    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  products     Product[] 
}
```

I am not seeing any compiletime error but getting error on website.
[image]

Comment: Did you run ```npx prisma generate``` when you edited the schema?

Comment: yes, did everything, ```npx prisma generate```, ```npx prisma migrate dev```, ```npx prisma db push```.
Nothing is helping. @SlothOverlord

Comment: This might be a silly issue, but did you save the schema file before doing those commands? This happened to me few times.  Also, try to uninstall and reinstall prisma.

Comment: solved by removing cache and re runnning `pnpm dev`

Answer (score 0):

solved by removing .next folder and runnning project again `pnpm dev`